# The method Console.Read() don't returns a string

Tags: c#, typeerror, console.readline

When I declare a variable "string x = Console.Read();" the message is shown: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'".

To test this, I made the console show the value I wrote in the input. I typed 5 in the input but the console showed me 53.

Why is this happening?

thank you in advance

public static void a21()
{

```
        System.Console.Write("Deseja ver a sequência até qual termo? ");
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
        int count = 0;

        int[] vetor = new int[n];

        while (count < n)
        {
            int quadrado = count * count;
            vetor[count] = quadrado;
            count++;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(vetor[i]);
        }
        System.Console.WriteLine(n);
    }
```

Comment: You typed all that and never stopped to read the documentation on `Console.Read`?

Comment: It's true; `Read()` doesn't return a string. Try `ReadLine()`

Answer (score 2):

[`Console.Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=net-6.0) returns an `int` containing the character that was read, or `-1` if nothing could be read.

It does not return a `string`.

If you want to read a string then use [`Console.ReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=net-6.0).

Answer (score 1):

> I typed 5 in the input but the console showed me 53.

Because `Console.Read()` read your char `'5'`, and returned it as an integer `53`, which is the decimal position on the ASCII table for char `'5'`:

[image]

`Convert.ToInt` did nothing to it, because it was already an int, so sending `53` into the conversion returns it as `53`.

If you print it (your code doesn't but I assume you did so to debug this), you get `53`